# Can ArcPy be imported in Python IDLE without ArcGIS Desktop installed on machine?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation, arcgis-license-manager

Can I import and run ArcPy on a standalone application without ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) installed in my machine?

Answer (score 7):

You can read all about [Accessing licenses and extensions in Python](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/access-to-licensing-and-extensions.htm) in the Online Help for ArcMap which starts:

> Whenever a tool is executed in a script, an ArcGIS license is
> required.

Assuming that ArcGIS Pro is also not installed, because your question predates that, I think the answer to your question is "Yes, but only if you have ArcGIS Engine or ArcGIS for Server installed and licensed instead".

Comment: Now that the Python3 flavor of ArcPy is available, this has a slightly different answer.

Comment: @Vince I’m happy for you to write another answer or edit mine (even heavily).

Comment: @Vince I edited to make ArcGIS Pro and thus Python 3.x out of scope for this Q&A.

Comment: I believe the ArcGIS API python environment can be installed as a standalone but this is not used for running arcpy tools, rather it’s for interacting with online content: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022005

Comment: @TheoF That refers to ArcGIS Pro and Python 3.x which is currently out of scope for this Q&A.  Also, I think the question was always about ArcPy rather than the ArcGIS Python API.